Как сделать, что бы пинговались два компьютера в разных подсетях по именам хостов, указанным в hosts?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Пусть есть два компьютера, PC1 (192.168.6.1/24) и PC2 (10.168.9.2/24).
Что надо сделать, что бы они пинговали друг друга по именам хостов, которые предварительно определены в файле hosts.
Для экспериментов, я взял два компьютера, присвоил такие же IP адреса ethernet адаптерам, соединил проводом ethernet адаптеры, но не  пингуется.
Что надо сделать или куда копать?

Если соединять два компьютера напрямую, то в свойствах сети у каждого нужно указать адрес шлюза, в данном случае просто адрес другого компьютера:

Для 192.168.1.24 указать 10.168.9.24.
Для 10.168.9.24 указать 192.168.1.24.

Должно работать. Если вдруг не будет, то нужно их сконфигурировать в одну сеть. Если используются выделенные (или хотя бы один) сетевые интерфейсы, то проблемы это не составляет.
При использовании маршрутизатора его адрес тоже указывается здесь.


Всех деталей уже не помню. Погуглите в этом направлении, если что.

Между ними нужно поставить маршрутизатор и настроить маршруты.
